# Google Structured Data Limitation

Tags: seo, google, structured-data

Is there a limitation of structured data pieces which google will index on my domain? It has stayed at precisely 100 for a couple of days now, my website has at least 120 though.

I guess it could just be because it hasn't finished indexing yet, but it makes me curious that it's at exactly 100.

Any information much appreciated, haven't seen anything on google so far about this.

Comment: I am sure there is no limit. Just one of those situations that make you say "Huummm..."

Comment: Here is someone asking essentially the same question. There is no solid answer, but the question is still interesting. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/nA7d09O1y6g

Comment: @closetnoc thanks for the information, I guess I'll wait a bit. If you wanna write an answer containing what you said, I'd be glad to accept it

Comment: I had not seen anything solid on limits either way. However, it does seem to be a behavior that has raised the question in others mind. Really, I think it is how Google spiders sites. After a big push, Google seems to take a bit of a break and goes back to the fresh pages for a while before another big push. So spidering pages does not really go in a linear fashion like we want. I sometimes make changes and it frustrates me the same way. @dhaupin is right and it seems to align with what I am saying but from more experience. So I will up-vote his answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a common thing with G. It seems to "test the waters" of your schema then disappears for awhile. This is consistent across sites large and small.

Anyways, there is no limit. We have some sites with 30k+ entities. It does take forever to index (or report index in GWT) though. Expect delays up to 8 months if your site is not freshened often. Even popular sites can take 2+ months to get all their schema entities recognized, then another month or so for G to actually put the widgets into SERPS.

PS: Make sure you **THOROUGHLY** check for errors with the test tool before pushing your schema live. An error will *stick* in GWT for a very long time. You can attempt to repair with fetch as Google, but it prob wont work. We had errors on some pages that were over a year old...basically a year later G finally revisited and realized "hey they must have fixed that schema snippet". Just be careful.

Comment: thanks for the insight. Didn't realize G is sooo slow, even for smaller sites. I guess I'm working on my traffic numbers now so that G is forced to index more often if they don't wanna miss out ;D